# Another Cassandra Data Modelling Approach

Tags: cassandra, data-analysis

I have read various sources on this subject and understand the idea of modelling around the queries needed but wondered how far this can be stretched for Cassandra.

I need to store processing events which contain both measures and dimension data if I was relating to a traditional data warehouse.
The format of the data is something like

log_timestamp (timestamp): user_id (text): measure_1 (num): measure_2 (num) : measure_3 (num) : dim_1 (text) : dim_2 (text) : ... dim_n(text)

where there may be 10 or more dim data items.
The queries I would like to model include :

user_id by time (minute/hour/day/week/month/year) with measure aggregates

user_id by single dim by time with measure aggregates

single dim by time with measure aggregates

some of the dimension fields form a natural hierarchy so I would like the above queries with more than one dim field as well.

Before embarking on the creation of a large number of discrete column families to try and cover the permutations I would like to know if anyone can recommend a better approach
e.g. using a single cf for the dim data with a column identifying the type of dim and another for the value and a similar idea for hierarchy data with the hierarchy type and member dims and values.

Alternatively what might be a good model for storing the data at a relatively granular level such that it could be read back out into an aggregation tool e.g. hive or spark (which looks really quite interesting).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to be able to query for aggregated data by week.  You could use the following data structure.

```
Column Family = day
Row Key: Date = day_identifier (e.g., time at beginning of some day this week)
Column Name: Date = timestamp, Long = field_ordinal
Column Value: field value

Column Family = week
Row Key: Date = week_identifier (e.g., time at beginning of first day of a week)
Column Name: Date = timestamp, Long = field_ordinal
Column Value: field value
```

At the end of each week, you'd take the entries in the day column family and aggregate them into an entry in the week column family.  Then you can remove the data per day if it's no longer that useful to you.

This concept allows you to store much less data, but you can still accomplish a lot.  For instance, if you want to query for data aggregated over a month, you'd just access all the weeks in that month.  Alternatively, you could use the same concept to roll up data for an entire month as well.

Good luck.